# Null pointer exception while doing unit testing using Mockito

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, junit4, dao

I am new with Mockito. I am writing unit test cases for `SomeDaoImplclass`

this is the method in `SomeDaoImplClass`

```
@Override 
Public SomeModelClass retriveSomeDetails(int a,long b){
    return retrieveSomeDetails(a,b,Enum.Active)
}
```

Here is my test class

```
@Mock
private SomeDaoImplClass someDaoImplClass

@Mock
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate

@Mock
DataSource dataSource

@Mock
SomeDaoClass someDaoClass

@Before
Public void setUp() throws Exception {
    someDaoImplClass = new SomeDaoImplClass();

    dataSource = Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);
    jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class);

    someDaoClass = Mockito.mock(SomeDaoClass.class);

    SomeDaoImplClass.setDataSource(dataSource);
    SomeDaoImplClass.setSomeDaoClass(someDaoClass);
}

@Test
public void testSomeData(){
    Modelclass modelclass = new ModelClass();
    Mockito.when(SomeDaoClass.retriveSomeDetails(Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(modelClass);
    ModelClass object2 = SomeDaoImplClass.retriveSomeDetails(01,1000L,Class.Active);
    Assert.assertEquals(01,1000L, object2);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does the code throw a null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i highly recommend to you, to take a look at [1] (but be careful to use the right version

Second you do make some initial mistakes.

1. you want to test `SomeDaoImplClass` but you are creating a mock, so you are not really testing the class
2. i do not see if you are using the `MockitoJUnitRunner`, but based on your code and implementation, i assume not. So you need to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` or use a `JUnitRule`
3. you are using static getters and setters to set your "DaoImplClass" and other needed classes, i do not know your implementation, but i am quite sure, it should be

   ```
   someDaoImplClass.setDataSource(daraSource);
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   SomeDaoImplClass.setDataSource(daraSource);
   ```
4. your test does not seem to make sense at the moment at all, what do you want to test? and what is your goal. You should definitely provide more context when asking questions, and review your whole "question" before posting

[1] http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html